# Testing android apps

Tags: android

What exactly are mock tests...I need to know the mock and performance tests available in android for testing android apps..what is the best tool for testing android apps and how..

Comment: You've now asked the same question three times in the space of three hours. Please read the answers to your questions rather than asking the same question over and over again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Android Eclipse plugin you can now create test projects. In fact every time you create an Android project it prompts you whether you want to create the equivalent Test project.

One thing I always found about Android testing tools is that they run pretty. Basically, my Android test strategy is to write independent modules for my application that run both on Android SDK and JDK platforms (this is actually not very hard to achieve with a few abstraction interfaces). Once you have that you can develop most of the application as a normal Java desktop application with normal JUnit tests that run blazing fast. Once you are done and tested with the module you integrate the jar into the Android application (mostly the UI layer).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the testing tool provided by android.

http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/testing-tools.html

Monkey testing is very popular so you can use that tool.

http://www.toptal.com/android/testing-like-a-true-green-droid